# Does Advanced Segments keep cookies for tracking visitors?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies, goal-tracking

I am working with Google Analytics - Goals and Funnels for quite sometime, but one thing is is not clear for me.

We are advertising on several sites rotating several different ads. Our main goal is to collect as many sign-ups (new users) as possible for as low price as possible.

We use to advertise the way, that each ad has the same URL where to land, but contains different parameter (e.g. http://www.brautpunkt.de/?ref=fb01 or ..... .De/?Ref=adw03).

My question is:
If I am looking at the goals (Goals Overview), filtering it through Advanced Segments (Landing Page contains /?Ref=fb01)

- Is this subset of goals done only by the users who registered in the same session after they came on our site directly from the ad?
- Or also by those users who came first time through this ad (/?Ref=fb01), didn't register in the same session but came directly for example on the other day and register than?

Peter

Comment: off-topic - this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Landing Page dimension isn't saved, it's only applicable to the session in which it occurred. To keep this in a cookie, you need to add [google analytics campaign tracking tags](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55518) to the links - then by default the most recent non-direct site access will get attribution for the conversion.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thank you very much. It looks promising. I am going to test it. I already changed the URL (added the google analytics campaign tracking tags) in the campaings. Will let you know. Kuko

Comment: Hi, I tested it and it works perfectly. I can also recommend to set up than a Custom Reporting in Analytics and there one can see the drill down from particular sources to campaigns and keywords.
Jamie, thanks again ;-)